# How can I make my lambda code be at the root of the folder if it's being uploaded as a zip file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, github-actions

I've created a CICD pipeline for a lambda on AWS to be updated everytime a push is made to its corresponding repo on github. The issue is that the lambda code can only be uploaded as a ZIP through CLI commands I'm running on Github Actions using the Lambda update-function-code API call.

However, if the file is uploaded as a zip, the lambda function is going to be one directory down from the root, resulting in errors with the handler.

Most prominently, I get the error:

```
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
```

And obviously index.handler is not found because it's one directory lower. But I can't upload the code directly for the lambda, I have to upload it as a zip file (which when, AWS unzips it, becomes a directory containing the code, hence it's one directory down).

Comment: Follow the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Comment: Why is the Lambda function going to be one directory down? Don't you have complete control over the creation of the ZIP file?

Comment: @jarmod It's because AWS doesn't extract the file contents from the zip directly, but puts them into a folder of the same name, so it's one directory lower than the root. I control the contents of the zip file & its creation, but AWS is the one extracting the contents when I upload the zip file.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here, but I don't use this workflow so can't easily verify. Can you extend the function handler configuration e.g. `somefolder.index.handler`?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you so much, I changed the function handler by adding the directory as a path (foldername/index.handler) and it ended up working out.